# Resize paragraph size (pixels) - Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, pixel, paragraph

I have a text paragraph. Is there a way of resizing it without having to pull the box or stretch it?

(ex. Let's say it's 50px high, how can I define the size of it using pixels to 100px?)

**EDIT:** How about an extension?

Comment: I don't think there is.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe there is an extension?

Comment: Great idea there! @DominicB-c you should have posted that as an answer! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no constraints on width and you can control how many lines of text are shown, you can use the font size and line-height to mathematically define it into 100px with (100px/number of lines).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of such functionality or plug-ins that can let you do it.

I'd suggest you use guides instead, or shapes, or even slices, something that will let you take advantage of `snap` (snap to guides, grid, layers, slices). You'd first need to create a skeleton of your measurements, and then create the text blocks using them as guides.

Comment: Thanx. I use the grids to snap it ;)